# How could I select the same field with different conditions in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

For example, I have the following tables :

```
account : ID, Login, Pass, Name

records : ID, Info, SubmitterID
```

And use the following command to select some data :

```
SELECT account.Name
    , records.Info
    FROM account, records
    WHERE account.ID = records.ID
```

Now I would like to display the Name field when `records.SubmitterID = account.ID` does anyone know if thats possible?

Thanks.

Comment: account.Name will be used in 2 different fields. One when account.ID = records.ID, and the other field when records.SubmitterID = account.ID. Hope this clarifies.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you probably want is:

```
SELECT account.Name, records.Info FROM account, records WHERE records.SubmitterID = account.ID
```

The two ID fields in your tables should not correspond to each other.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT a.Name
FROM account a
INNER JOIN records r ON (r.SubmitterID = a.ID)
```

Answer (score 0):

I may misunderstand your question, buy why don't you just use an or statement...

```
SELECT account.Name, records.Info 
FROM account, records 
WHERE account.ID = records.ID OR account.id=records.submitterID
```

Answer (score 0):

you have account -> N: records.
Account and records are related with account.ID=records.SubmitterID

```
Select account.name,records.info from ACCOUNT INNER JOIN records ON account.ID=records.SubmitterID
```